# How to create CAF Receiver?

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

In recently, Google upgrade its cast receiver to version V3.

There is a simple demo in google demo page as below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <cast-media-player id="player"></cast-media-player>
  <style>
    #player {
        --theme-hue: 210;
        --splash-image: url("my.png");
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    const context = cast.framework.CastReceiverContext.getInstance();
    const playerManager = context.getPlayerManager();

    // intercept the LOAD request to be able to read in a contentId and get data
    playerManager.setMessageInterceptor(
        cast.framework.messages.MessageType.LOAD, loadRequestData => {
            if (loadRequestData.media && loadRequestData.media.contentId) {
                return thirdparty.getMediaById(loadRequestData.media.contentId)
                .then(media => {
                  if (media) {
                    loadRequestData.media.contentUrl = media.url;
                    loadRequestData.media.contentType = media.contentType;
                    loadRequestData.media.metadata = media.metadata;
                  }
                  return loadRequestData;
                });
            }
            return loadRequestData;
        });

    // listen to all Core Events
    playerManager.addEventListener(cast.framework.events.category.CORE,
        event => {
            console.log(event);
        });

    const MyCastQueue = class extends cast.framework.QueueBase {
        initialize(loadRequestData) {
            const media = loadRequestData.media;
            const items = [];
            items.push(myCreateItem(media)); // your custom function logic

            const queueData = new cast.framework.messages.QueueData();
            queueData.items = items;

            return queueData;
        }

        nextItems(itemId) {
           return [myCreateNextItem()]; // your custom function logic
        }
    };

    const playbackConfig = new cast.framework.PlaybackConfig();

    // Sets the player to start playback as soon as there are five seconds of
    // media contents buffered. Default is 10.
    playbackConfig.autoResumeDuration = 5;

    const myCastQueue = new MyCastQueue(); // create instance of queue Object

    context.start({queue: myCastQueue, playbackConfig: playbackConfig});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#styling-the-player

But when I debugged it, there is an error that `'thirdparty' is undefined`.

Does anyone can show me how to create a CAF receiver?

Comment: Based form this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging#game-ui), if you encounter this kind of error, you may need to update or reinstall the Google Cast extension. Just follow through this [Create a Basic CAF Receiver App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic) documentation for more information.

Comment: Please file a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is example code. You are supposed to provide those extra functions yourself.

The example shows how to override the queueing system to perform receiver based queueing. It isn't a great example IMHO as it doesn't provide an example of asynchronously fetching server based queues.

If you don't need receiver managed queues you can start with the minimal CAF receiver shown on the previous page. This is enough to get the remote debugger working which is at least one good reason to have a custom receiver.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic

I've made a more complete example. https://gist.github.com/jcable/45c65a72074763a9ec30ddb1ff217517

Comment: By the way, there were errors in the documentation which are now fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your demo, and it works.
In Chromecast Receiver V3, We don't need to manage UI events anymore. The SDK handle it for us. That's great!

Comment: Great! glad it was useful. Would you mind up-voting the answer?

Comment: I am sorry.                                                                                                                                Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.